# VBA arrays and variants

Tags: vba, excel

VBA arrays and variant arrays are confusing me!

If I have a two dimensional array that is essentially a range on a spreadsheet, is there a way to set a 1 dimensional new array that is equal to just one of those columns in the 2 dimensional array?

Does that make sense?

Edit:

I have a spreadsheet that is a quote template.  Some of these products that I am quoting are products that we do not want to quote because they do not meet our guidelines.

I want to go through these rows of products and identify which ones are bad by checking if the product has a field that says “kick”.  If it does, then I am going to make other fields for that row (product) a kick as well.  Simple macro.  The problem is that I come from Python and C and I tend to think of these spreadsheets as a bunch of 1 dimensional arrays and I usually write loops to go through them.

What I have done in the past is take that range and I just create a bunch of 1 dimensional arrays that I then loop through with a “for loop” or a “for each loop”.  That approach works fine, but it is a pain to assign all the 1dimensional arrays.  Today I thought, well maybe there is a way I just do the same thing but with a 2 dimensional array, since it would be easy to quickly assign a whole range as a 2 dimensional array.

Anyway, the problem I am having is that I do not know how to reference just one dimension(col) of a two dimensional array.

Can I do a for each loop on one column of a 2D array?

Comment: When you say _essentially_ - is actually a range OR an array?

Comment: I have been experimenting with using an actual range, and then use the values of that range to populate an array.  I am not sure which is the better approach for what I want to do.

Comment: Let me work up a quick summary of what I am trying to do because maybe I am going about this wrong.

Comment: Edited my question and added more detail on what I am doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Range objects are quite flexible in Excel.  You can do what you want in many ways.  I'll give two examples:

```
For i = 1 to 10
     b = Range("yourRange").Cells(i, yourColumn) + 1
 Next i
```

If you assign a constant value to the column you can easily loop through the rows as shown.  Or if you're more comfortable with a For Each loop:

```
For each c in Range("yourRange").Columns(1)
     b = c + 1
Next
```

VBA treats every Excel range as a 2-Dimensional array in any case.  You can even use normal array syntax like: `Range("yourRange")(row, col)`

Comment: Thanks, I didn't even think of using the .Columns property.  That will definitely help some of my issues.  I think that some of my VBA problems comes about from confusion about range datatypes.  I mean what is a range?  I would have expected a range to be a collections of cells and that I could somehow access a single cell and I could then use TypeName() on it to return a type of cell.  Instead, I seem to still get a type of range!  It gets confusing!

Comment: @TimothyBramlett, in Excel, a cell is a range.  It is simply a 2-dimensional array with only 1 member in each dimension.  It's really flexible in VBA.  You can use `Range("range").Cells(row,col)` or `Range(x).Column(y).Cells(row,col)`, etc.

Comment: Ok, so that is really interesting then.  So, when I declare something as a range, then I am not giving it a location, I am actually declaring it as a collection of cells and it has all the normal properties that a cell/range would.  See, I was thinking of a range as like a location or address that referred to some group of other objects.

Comment: I can see how it would be confusing for someone used to the complexity of C/C++ or Java, etc.  You can get a Python library to work with excel files if all you need are the values.

Comment: Well and C is more precise to me in some ways.  It doesn't usually do things to help me that cause me to not understand what is going on later on down the road.  But then again it takes forever to develop in C.  Python  would be fantastic to work in for this, but unfortunately I need VBA because I am building a small application that is actually in Excel.  Still, I am probably just having these problems because I don't have that much experience in VB/VBA.  I always heard that VBA is a nightmare but I have found that it is not too bad to work in! :)

Comment: @TimothyBramlett, VBA the language is not bad... interfacing with Office products is where you'll find the problems.

Comment: I keep getting a type mismatch when I try to debug.print the contents of a column by using range.columns.  Any ideas?

Comment: You have to use the Join function to convert and array to a string.

Answer (score 1):

This illustrates use of 1-D or 2-D arrays from a range

```
Sub GetCellDataInArrays()

    Dim rng As Range, a, a2, data, r, c

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:D12")

    'get a column: Transpose creates a 1-D array
    a = Application.Transpose(rng.Columns(2).Value)

    Debug.Print "Column 2: ", Join(a, ",")

    'get a row - note the double Transpose
    a2 = Application.Transpose(Application.Transpose( _
                 rng.Rows(3).Value))

    Debug.Print "Row 3:", Join(a2, ",")


    'EDIT: how to loop over a 2-D array obtained from a worksheet range
    data = rng.Value 'data is a 2-d 1-based array
    For r = 1 To UBound(data, 1)
        For c = 1 To UBound(data, 2)
            Debug.Print "Row " & r & ":Col " & c & " = ", data(r, c)
        Next c
    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: Nice example for tutorial purposes (+1)